# Error de conexion php con SQL server

Tags: php, sql-server

estoy probando una conexion a SQL server desde PHP. Ya descargue los controladores y configure XAMP. Puse un codogo sencillo para la probar la conexion:

```
"<?php
     $serverName = "14.0.1000.169";
     $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"MISTRAL", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"pass");
     $con = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
      
      if($con){
         echo "Conexion exitosa"; 
      }else{
          echo "Fallo en la conexion"; 
          die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
      }
?>"
```

***Resultado:*** Fallo en la conexionArray ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IM006 [SQLSTATE] => IM006 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][Administrador de controladores ODBC] Error de SQLSetConnectAttr del controlador [message] => [Microsoft][Administrador de controladores ODBC] Error de SQLSetConnectAttr del controlador ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 01000 [SQLSTATE] => 01000 [1] => 5701 [code] => 5701 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Changed database context to 'MISTRAL'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Changed database context to 'MISTRAL'. ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 01000 [SQLSTATE] => 01000 [1] => 5703 [code] => 5703 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Changed language setting to us_english. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Changed language setting to us_english. ) )

Comment: Intenta poner el puerto donde está ejecutándose la base de datos: `$serverName = "14.0.1000.169, AQUINUMERODEPUERTO";` Por cierto ese valor `1000` en la IP es muyyyy raro ¿no? ¿Seguro que esa es la IP correcta? Verifica eso y si no funciona, quizá debas poner también el nombre de la instancia. [Revisa la doc para más detalles](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sqlsrv-connect.php).

Comment: Gracias por responder amigo, ya probe con la instancia y el puerto pero sigue igual.

Comment: Al ponerle puerto mepone otro error:

Comment: Agrega también el error que te da cuando pones el puerto. También, verifica que esa sea la IP correcta donde está la BD. Dinos también si es una conexión remota y, de ser así, verifica que la IP del cliente desde el que intentas conectarte está autorizada.

Comment: Me pone este error con el puerto por defecto que es : 1433, no pongo el error completo porque excede la cantidad de caracteres-------------------Fallo en la conexionArray ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IM006 [SQLSTATE] => IM006 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][Administrador de controladores ODBC] Error de SQLSetConnectAttr del controlador [message] => [Microsoft][Administrador de controladores ODBC] Error de SQLSetConnectAttr del controlador ) [1] => Array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quiero agradecer a los que se tomaron un tiempo para tratar de responder mi pregunta. Al fin di con la respuesta. El problema radica en que yo estaba usando los drivers ODBC 13 para sql con una version de PHP 8.0.6. Para esa version de PHP corresponden los controladores referentes a la version 5.9 cuyo descargable tiene este nombre "SQLSRV59.EXE", lo cual habia hecho correctamente. Lo que estaba mal eran los drivers **ODBC** los que coresponden para SQL server 2017 con PHP 8.0.6 son *ODBC Driver 17* cuyo descargable tiene este nombre: "msodbcsql.msi".
Espero ayude a los que se encuentren en con esa situacion. Aqui les dejo el link que contiene las tablas de versiones y drivers
[Rquerimientos para drivers PHP para sql server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-ver15#driver-versions)

Answer (score 0):

La razón más común que este intento de conexión es que este origen de datos DSN u ODBC, intentado realizar una conexión mediante TCP/IP sockets de biblioteca de red, que es Dbmssocn.dll. Porque el SQL Server no escucha las conexiones entrantes de los clientes de sockets TCP/IP, se produce un error en la conexión. Desde ISQL/w, se devolvería el segundo mensaje de error indicado anteriormente. El Error del sistema operativo es 10061, y la llamada de función que no era ConnectionOpen(connect()).

Comment: Gracias por responder amigo, aun no se como resolver el problema